# how to determine that an element is button or text box

Tags: javascript, jquery

How I can determine that an element is a `input` is a `button` type or is a `text` type in jquery?

thanks

Comment: As you can probably see from the answers, there is some confusion over what you actually mean. I read your question as "an element that is an `input`, a `button` or a `textarea`. Is that correct? Or did you mean "an `input` element of type `button` or `text`"?

Comment: or did you mean "if an element is an `input text` or an `input button`"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('input').attr('type')
```

or

```
$('input').prop('type')
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vSsgD/)**

or

```
$('input').is(':button');

$('input').is(':text');
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vSsgD/1/)**

or

```
$(target)[0].tagName
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vSsgD/2/)**

Comment: @FlorianMargaine: But the OP's question is clear that it's an `input`. @ thecodeparadox: I'd go with `input` rather than `:input` for that reason.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder OP's question is clearly not clear about that. That's why I upvoted James' answer.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - I read the question as asking if an element is an `input`, a `button` or a `textarea` (not the type of an `input`).

Comment: @JamesAllardice: I see what you mean.

Comment: for extra information: I thinks my Asp.net button convert to `button` element but it convert to `submit` input.so I should check `.is(':submit');` either.thanks

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Ok, now the question has been edited, I think I misunderstood the question. +1 to you and thecodeparadox.

Comment: @JamesAllardice: And here when I went back and re-read (before the edit), I thought *you'd* read it right. :-) I just covered both bases in my answer (no one had up till then).

Answer (score 1):

If you have:

```
var field = $("some selector that finds the input");
```

Then

```
field[0].tagName
```

...will be either `INPUT` or `BUTTON` or `SELECT` or `TEXTAREA`, telling you what tag was used to create the field.

If it's `INPUT`, then

```
field[0].type
// or
field.attr('type')
// or
field.prop('type')
```

...will be the type of `input` tag (e.g. `"text"`, `"button"`, etc.).

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ubeseh) | [source](http://jsbin.com/ubeseh/edit):

HTML:

```
<input type="text" value="text field">
<br><input type="button" value="input button">
<br><select><option>select</option></select>
<br><textarea>textarea</textarea>
<br><button>button</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
jQuery(function($) {

  $("input, select, textarea, button").each(function(index) {
    var msg;
    var field = $(this);
    msg = "[" + index + "]: tagName is " + field[0].tagName;
    if (field[0].tagName === "INPUT") {
      msg += ", and type is " + field.prop('type');
    }
    display(msg);
  });

  function display(msg) {
    $("<p>").html(msg).appendTo(document.body);
  }
});
```

Output:

```
[0]: tagName is INPUT, and type is text
[1]: tagName is INPUT, and type is button
[2]: tagName is SELECT
[3]: tagName is TEXTAREA
[4]: tagName is BUTTON
```

Note that I only used `field = $(this)` there so that we'd have a jQuery wrapper around each of the elements. If you have a raw DOM element reference already (as we do in that loop, as `this`), no need to do that, just use `elm.tagName` and `elm.type` directly.

Answer (score 0):

Check the tag name of the element:

```
element.prop('tagName')
```

For `<input>` tags, also check the type:

```
element.prop('type');
```